Trying to make a pig dice game, but the score resets every turn
For a class project I have to make this dice game in python, and the one thing I cannot solve is that the total_score variable reses back to 0 at the start of each player's turn. I believe it is because the value is not properly being stored, but cannot find a solution.
import math, random

def print_instructions():
    print("""Welcome to Pig Dice. Get 2 to 10 players and one 6 sided die. During a player's turn, they may roll the die as many times as they wish. At the end of their turn, add all of their points together and pass the die to the next person. However, if they roll a one, they lose all points gained, and that turn ends. First one to score 100 points wins.""")


def get_Player_names ():
    print("You will need 2 to 10 players!")
    done = False
    players = []
    while not done:
        player = input("Names of players(hit enter to quit): ")
        if len(player)>0:
            players.append(player)
        else:
            done=True
    print()
    return players

def process_player_turn(player_name,total_score,turn_score):
    choice = input(f"{player_name} would you like to roll or pass? ")
    while choice == ("roll"):
        player_value = random.randint(1,6)
        print(f"{player_name} rolled a {player_value}")       
        turn_score = turn_score + player_value
        
        if player_value == 1:
            turn_score = 0
            print(f"{player_name} rolled a 1! Turn over!")
            print("Total score:", total_score)
            break
        
        if total_score >= 100:
            print(f"{player_name}'s score:", total_score, f"{player_name} Wins!")
            return True
        
        choice = input(f"{player_name} would you like to roll again? ")
        
    else:
        total_score = total_score + turn_score
        print("Total score:", total_score, "Turn ended.")
        turn_score = 0
        
 
    print()
    return False


def main():
    total_score = 0
    turn_score = 0
    print_instructions()
    player_names = get_Player_names()

    done = False
    while not done:
        for player_name in player_names:
            done = process_player_turn(player_name,total_score,turn_score)
            if done:
                break


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()


Python variables are passed by value, not by reference. Assigning to total_score and turn_score in process_player_turn doesn't affect the variables in main. You need to return the new values of these variables and assign them back to the variables.

You keep calling process_player_turn(0, 0, player_name) with no attempt to return or otherwise store the changed scores.

Looks like a scope issue, you can put a global turn_score on the line after def main(): or handle it some less mutable way, and pass the value out from inside the function, by say updating or passing it along on each rotation.

You're never returning the score from your processing function, would you like this demonstrated, I can also demonstrate other ways of organizing the whole thing?

@Maka, please never advise using global vars, especially to rookies.

I totally appreciate the sentiment. But then I wouldn't use a mutable state at all. If people want to write like that, which all these tutorials do then it's already starting off on that foot and difficult to gauge what kind of answer they are looking for.

In this while loop you are always passing player_name,0,0 to function process_player_turn because you are passing by value not passing by reference.
while not done:
    for player_name in player_names:
        done = process_player_turn(player_name,total_score,turn_score)
        if done:
            break

You may try to return the values back.
Here is the solution:
import math, random

def print_instructions():
    print("""Welcome to Pig Dice. Get 2 to 10 players and one 6 sided die. During a player's turn, they may roll the die as many times as they wish. At the end of their turn, add all of their points together and pass the die to the next person. However, if they roll a one, they lose all points gained, and that turn ends. First one to score 100 points wins.""")


def get_Player_names ():
    print("You will need 2 to 10 players!")
    done = False
    players = []
    while not done:
        player = input("Names of players(hit enter to quit): ")
        if len(player)>0:
            players.append(player)
        else:
            done=True
    print()
    return players

def process_player_turn(player_name,total_score,turn_score):
    choice = input(f"{player_name} would you like to roll or pass? ")
    while choice == ("roll"):
        player_value = random.randint(1,6)
        print(f"{player_name} rolled a {player_value}")       
        turn_score = turn_score + player_value
        
        if player_value == 1:
            turn_score = 0
            print(f"{player_name} rolled a 1! Turn over!")
            print("Total score:", total_score)
            break
        
        if total_score >= 100:
            print(f"{player_name}'s score:", total_score, f"{player_name} Wins!")
            return True
        
        choice = input(f"{player_name} would you like to roll again? ")
        
    else:
        total_score = total_score + turn_score
        print("Total score:", total_score, "Turn ended.")
        turn_score = 0
        
 
    print()
    return False, total_score, turn_score


def main():
    total_score = 0
    turn_score = 0
    print_instructions()
    player_names = get_Player_names()

    done = False
    while not done:
        for player_name in player_names:
            done, total_score, turn_score = process_player_turn(player_name, total_score, turn_score)
            if done:
                break


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()


For simplicity you can merge all functions into one. Then you don't need to think about variables accessibility:
import random

MAX_SCORE = 100
print(f"""Welcome to Pig Dice. Get 2 to 10 players and one 6 sided die.
During a player's turn, they may roll the die as many times as they wish.
At the end of their turn, add all of their points together and pass the die to the next person.
However, if they roll a one, they lose all points gained, and that turn ends.
First one to score {MAX_SCORE} points wins.""")
players = []
while True:
    name = input("Player name (hit enter to quit): ")
    if name:
        players.append(name)
    else:
        break

total_score = 0
while True:
    for player in players:
        turn_score = 0
        while True:
            choice = input(f"{player} would you like to roll or pass? ")
            if choice == "roll":
                value = random.randint(1, 6)
                print(f"{player} rolled a {value}")
                turn_score += value

                if value == 1:
                    turn_score = 0
                    print(f"{player} rolled a 1! Turn over!")
                    print("Total score:", total_score)
                    break
            else:
                total_score += turn_score
                print("Total score:", total_score, "Turn ended.")
                break

        if total_score >= MAX_SCORE:
            print(f"{player}'s score:", total_score, f"{player} Wins!")
            break

